# Django: ValidationError as ugettext or ugettext_lazy

Tags: django

I read a lot about ugettext and ugettext_lazy now. I understand _lazy is mostly for these things:

- models.py (fields, verbose_name, help_text, methods
  short_description);
- forms.py (labels, help_text, empty_label);
- apps.py (verbose_name)

ugettext for these:

- views.py
- Other modules similar to view functions that are executed during the
  request process

([Source](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/10/17/django-tip-18-translations.html))

However I am still not sure, should ValidationError's then also be done with ugettext_lazy?

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

    def check_if_form_is_empty(self):
        [...]
        if not quantities:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _("You didn't choose any tickets."), # TODO _ for translations
                    code='no_tickets',
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not really understood the point of `ugettext_lazy`. That is for use in places where you do not yet know what the current language is; particularly, in class-level attributes like fields on models and forms. There's no request at the point those are defined, so you have to use a lazy method.

Your code is inside a method, and though you don't show where it is called it appears to be some kind of validation, which will only be called in the context of a user operation. So no, you do not need to use the lazy method here.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for answering so quickly. I think I get your point. So all the class-level attributes such as fields, labels etc. which are only executed once (when starting Django) they don't know yet which language the user will choose. Therefore _lazy will not translate it until that's defined?